# Debugging VC++ DLL suddenly stops working

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, interop, com-interop

Basically I have a C# app under traditional .NET 4.5 that references a DLL built in VC++.

Now I need to debug the code within the VC++ DLL (COM Server) referenced so I put some breakpoints there.
Once I reach those breakpoints I start to do step over (F10) and step into (F11) in order to debug the code step by step. I am able to debug some lines of code but suddenly debugging stops working randomly when performing step over/into and then Visual Studio hangs (not responding).

So any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: Is your Visual Studio up to date? Any 3rd party that could hook in and mess it up?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I have recently updated Visual Studio 2019 and for now there is no more updates. Well I am using a "special" type of Windows, it is a Windows ARM (because I am virtualizing it with Parallels on a Mac with M1 chip - ARM architecture, not intel-based) and I run visual studio on it (Yes, i know it is said that VS is not fully compatible with M1 chip, in fact, you are advised with a warning message when you install it). But I don't know if i am doing something wrong or maybe the cause is .... (to be continued next post)

Comment: @SimonMourier or maybe the cause is the ARM architecture. Also my C# app is compiled as "Any CPU" target and VC++ DLL as x86 target. Then once launched, from task manager I see that in columns "platform" and "Architecture" my C# app figures as 64 bits and ARM64(x64 compatible) respectively and the VC++ DLL figures as 32 bits and x86 respectively so I do not know if it is the problem.  Could a 64 bits process call a 32 bits process? I guess it is possible.

Comment: @SimonMourier Also if I compile my C# app targeting to x64 instead of AnyCPU, I see in task manager the same for both columns: 64 bits and ARM64 (x64 compatible) for platform and architecture columns respectively. I do not know if this is really the culprit, I mean, the ARM architecture that makes weird things when calling a VC++ DLL in 32bits and x86 architecture and hence that debugging process stops randomly, but... I don't know.

Comment: Yes 64 bits and 32 bits processes can communicate, but your whole config is a bad smell :-). With Visual Studio, if you need ARM/ARM64 support it's only supported to develop everything on a x86/x64 machine, and just run everything on ARM/ARM64 (using emulation or not). *"Visual Studio is only supported on devices using a x86 or AMD64/x64 based processor."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-on-arm-devices?view=vs-2022

Comment: Those M1 chips are supposed to be very efficient at x86 emulation, maybe you want to try x86 (or x86_64) version of Windows and Visual Studio...

Comment: You said you're debugging the out-of-process COM server DLL?  I assume you either changed the Debug launch to run the out-of-process host EXE or attached to it, and set the breakpoints in context of the out-of-process COM server.  Because that DLL doesn't load in the C# EXE, setting breakpoints on the C++ code while debugging the C# project won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Try project's property and change debugger type to Mixed or Native Only.[image: from Auto]

Comment: I wonder if the person who marked this answer down would have enough courage to substantiate this. I do not do it for points but it is frustrating because my post is a legitimate attempt to answer the question and give steps to rectify the problem. I have had many problems using Auto settings debugging mixed code. 
From my experience, this step could help resolve this issue. If not in this particular case that is not the reason to mark it down in my opinion.
I think the rule for marking down should be changed and whoever does that should provide a reason for doing so.